# What is the justification of the title being a link?

Tags: hyperlink, title

I saw this in so many websites even in Stackoverflow and i never understood why is the title a link. is this has to do something whit search engines or is it some design feature?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "title" - the logo, or the page title? Where, on which page?

Comment: nono .. exactly how on this page "What is the justification of the title being a link?" is a link

Comment: He means the question title. On every question. It could be a short-hand to access the original question link, without having to manually remove any anchors that exist when you load the page from your inbox. But I don't know the real intent behind it...

Comment: Yes but not just here i saw this on many site

Comment: the reason may be permalinking as @Irfy says: When you click the title, you get a canonical, clean link to the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, there are many page-internal links on a page. When you click them, you get various anchors and perhaps other query parameters which somehow influence the page.

When you provide a link via a title, you are providing a way to always have a *clean*, *canonical* link to the page (credit to @Pekka for the wording ;-))